# Automatic Image Slide to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scroll

I am searching for a script which automatically scrolls a vertical image (in a DIV which is not as high as the image) from his top to the bottom and stop there.

Vertical image sliders on web most are for more than 1 image and repeats after the images and that isn't what I want.

Is there anyone with an idea?

Greets,
Tom

Comment: could you animate the margin property of the image within the div? what have you tried?

Comment: As yet I only tried scripts like this [link](http://javascript.about.com/library/blcvert.htm) and from the jquery-library cause in javascript I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

http://jsfiddle.net/ReeQ9/1/

You would need to play with the numbers a little to make it work for your image but you should be able to see how it works.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="img" src="http://matchingradar.co.uk/Images/fade-2.jpg" />    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{height:50px;width:460px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.img{position:absolute;width:460px;bottom:0px;}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.img').animate({bottom: "-=200px"} ,500);
});
```

You could even be more clever and get the height of you image and the height of you div and then not have to play with the numbers but i'll leave that to you! :P